# preg_replace() tags with some parameters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

how can i remove tags that is have (style="display:none")
for example in below text:

```
  <div style="text-align:center;clear:both;width:100%">
 <img src="http://url"  style="border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-width: initial; border-color: initial;">
 <div style="width:100%;display:none">
 <p style="text-align:center;color:#000">blahblah  </p>
 </div></div>
 <p style="text-align: justify;display:none">
 <span>
 <strong style="color:#E02C89">blahblahblahblah </strong></span></p>
 <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">blahblah</div>
```

how should i remove none displayed tag and keep others

i test this below pattern but it does not work properly:

```
$x = preg_replace ("/<p(.*?)display\s?:\s?none(.*?)>(.*?)<\/p>/is", "", $x);
```

Comment: Try `/display:none/g` pattern!

Comment: Not worth reopening. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php